Login screen suddenly extended over two displays, because of new phantom display?
Since the last update my login screen is suddenly extended over two displays which is annyoing since I have to somehow scroll with the mouse to move the login prompt into the view. I feels like the login screen is as big as both of my screens together.
I guess the last update screwed the monitor settings and the login is a side effect (it was a kernel update and it screwed my network settings as well!). There are suddenly 3 monitors in display settings. In Nvidia config, "X screen 0" is a container for both monitors. I'm not sure if this was before and somehow I think that gdm uses this "X screen 0" as default.

But in display config, I have an additional monitor 1 "Unknown Display" and when I activate is, it is as big as my big monitor.

The real monitors start with number 2 and 3. I guess this leads to this weird behaviour on the login page. I cannot even remove this "Unknown Display". Any ideas what I can do?

I have something similar going on, and your question prompted me to look at my display settings. I, too, have sometime in the last week or so, grown a phantom "unknown display." I use auto-login, so in my case, the symptoms are slightly different (my desktop upon reboot now exceeds the size of my screen, forcing me to access my display settings, set it to a smaller resolution, then cancel that change and revert, upon which the display is correct again). EDIT: to clarify, I only have 1 monitor.

This question is similar to: How do disable/get rid of PRIME display?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@amar this is different, because the main problem was the misaligned login screen (see topic of this question). The solution was to disable the monitor buit this was not clear in the first place, but at first it was not clear how to solve it.

I found a workaround which is acceptable for me. When you execute xrandr you see the name of the phantom monitor. For me it was None-1-1.
Now create a file with the following content:
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/disable-ghost-monitor.conf 
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "None-1-1"
    Option "Ignore" "true"
EndSection

After reboot, GDM ignores this phantom monitor and the GDM prompt is properly aligned again. In display settings, the phantom monitor is also gone...

